# understanding safari SVG redraw bug fix.

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I was just going through **[THIS](http://snapsvg.io/demos/#globe)** snap sbg demo and i came across the following lines of code:

```
var flag,
    len = Snap.path.getTotalLength(pth.attr("d"));
Snap.animate(0, len, function (l) {
    // Safari bug workaround: forcing redraw
    g.attr({width: 100 + (flag = !flag ? 1e-5 : 0) + "%"});
    //
    var dot = pth.getPointAtLength(l);
    flight.attr({
        d: pth.getSubpath(0, l)
    });
    pln.attr({
        transform: "t" + [dot.x, dot.y] +
                   "r" + (dot.alpha - 90)
    });
    gr.attr({
        transform: getShift(dot)
    });
}, 10000);
```

Now i am not quite understanding the below line of code:

```
g.attr({width: 100 + (flag = !flag ? 1e-5 : 0) + "%"});
```

What exactly is `1e-5` ? can somebody explian ?

Comment: [Scientific notation of small or large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation), in this case, 0.00001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
flag = (!flag ? 1e-5 : 0) + "%"
```

is the same as:

```
if(!flag) {
    flag = 0.00001; //1e-5 is the scientific notation for 1^-5
} else {
    flag = 0;
}

flag = flag + "%";
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Snap, but it seems like the code is changing the width property every frame from 100% to 100.00001%, causing a redraw. 1e-5, as mentoined in comments is number written using scientific notation for real numbers and is equal to 10^-5 = 0.00001.